# Fullcalendar Recurring Events All Show 12am Time

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I store my event dates in mySQL as datetime and with fullcalendar version 4, they show properly throughout.   I am working on adding recurring events to the calendar now, but when I do, all my recurring events show with a 12am start time, despite what my actual event dates/times are.

Have a look at what happens in code pen.  I have the original code attached also for reference.

I was thinking that perhaps I am not storing the date and time correctly for the recurring events, but as I said, they do show properly until I make them a recurring event.

https://codepen.io/michels287/pen/eaBmxN?editors=0010

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    selectMirror: true,
    plugins: ['interaction', 'resourceDayGrid', 'resourceTimeGrid'],
    header: {
        right: 'prevYear,prev,next,today,nextYear',
        center: 'title',
        left: 'resourceTimeGridDay,resourceTimeGridTwoDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
    },
    views: {
        resourceTimeGridTwoDay: {
            type: 'resourceTimeGrid',
            duration: {
                days: 2
            },
            buttonText: '2 days',
        }
    },
    defaultView: 'resourceTimeGridDay',
    datesAboveResources: true,
    editable: true,
    nowIndicator: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    events: [ { 
      allDay: false,
      color: "#FFD700",
      company_id: "1",
      startTime: "2019-05-13 14:00:00",
      endTime: "2019-05-13 14:00:00",
      id: "22218",
      daysOfWeek: [0,1,2],
      resourceId: "1"  }],
         resources: [{
            id: '1',
            title: 'Room A'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            title: 'Room B'
        }
    ]
});

calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: "startTime" and "endTime" should be just that - _times_, not _dates_. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events says "startTime" and "endTime" must be "Something that will parse into a Duration." The Duration article https://fullcalendar.io/docs/duration-object (which that statement links to says  that, when supplied as a string (like yours), the duration must be "a string in the format hh:mm:ss.sss, hh:mm:sss or hh:mm". Clearly, your values, which include dates as well as time, doesn't meet that criteria. Here's a simple working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmNPeJ?editors=0010

Comment: Even if what you'd written worked, it's unclear what you were trying to achieve - You've specified it to recur on 3 days per week, but then the start/end times had it starting and ending on a single day...so restricting it to appearing once. A recurring event which only occurs once? I can't really work out what you had intended there?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the confusion.  I was using datetime formats for my normal start/end events, so I **assumed** I could carry that logic over to startTime and endTime.  You are right, I misread the docs.

I changed startTime and endTime to type 'time' in my db and are loading times as you are showing.

If anyone else comes across this and finds it useful, the startRecur and endRecur fields are stored in my db as 'date' also.  I'm only using dates like '2019-05-13' for instance to get them to work.

If those fields (the recurring event fields) are populated in my db, I no longer store anything in the usual 'start' and 'end' fields which is used to show normal events!  With that said, I am also fetching the dates from my db using the 'start' and 'end' date parameters to load as needed when the calendar is moved forward-backward by the user.

In order to make this work with my recurring events, I doing querying like this:

```
SELECT non_recurring_event_fields_here FROM appointments appts WHERE (appts.start BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."') 

    UNION ALL

SELECT recurring_event_fields_are_here FROM appointments appts WHERE appts.start IS NULL
```

By doing the UNION ALL query afterwards it will grab all my recurring events and will show on the client side (thanks to fullcalendar's js) however they are designed in my db: with startRecur, endRecur, startTime, endTime, daysOfWeek, etc.

ADyson, I understand now how recurring events work based on your comments and suggestions.  I am aware of how much you've helped me thus far on my update to fullcalendar 4 from 3.  I will be paying for the license once this is complete, so your efforts will not go to waste.

Thanks again.

Comment: glad you fixed it. BTW you don't need two union two separate queries here, just write `WHERE (appts.start BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."') OR appts.start IS NULL` in the first query

Comment: P.S. I have nothing to do with the fullCalendar project and won't receive a penny of your license money. I volunteer here because I enjoy fixing code and solving problems (and because it can get you noticed by recruiters :-) ). But thanks for your appreciation and kind words.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I don't need the UNION, you're right!  Ha!  Great job, again.   After I submitted that response, I was thinking that I hoped you DID work with the fullcalendar team!  I do appreciate it.    I'm a self taught programmer so I learn a lot yet as I go.  Thanks again.